# VB6 SQL connection string set up issues

Tags: sql, vb6

I'm trying to get an old VB6 application running so I can see how it works and replicate its functionality in an MVC web app. In order to get it running I had to create a test database. To get all the data in I restored a backup from the current database, so it's an exact copy of the environment the application currently runs in. In order to make this work I figured I'd have to just update the connection string, but every time I try to run it I get the error: 
“[DNETLIB][ConnecionOpen (Connect().]SQL Server does not exist or access denied."

My current connection string is:

```
Set Cn = New ADODB.Connection
Cn.Open _
  "Provider=SQLOLEDB;" & _
  "Data Source=WIN-HO6SNPJR0ST\TestDB;" & _
  "Initial Catalog=TestDB;" & _
  "UID=Test;" & _
  "PWD=test;"
```

The user "Test" has full admin rights on the database.

I'm doing all the debugging in VB6 so I'm unfamiliar with the IDE, so I may be over looking an easier way to trouble shoot this other than break points.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure you need the single quotes for the data source?

Comment: @Oded I just tried it without the quotes and got the same error. All my experience is with C# and Java. That's why I think I just have to be typing it wrong.

Comment: Take a look at http://connectionstrings.com - look for your database and for the oledb provider.

Comment: Check out this Microsoft support post, http://support.microsoft.com/kb/888228

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Does this still apply if the SQL server is on the same machine that I'm running this on?

Comment: Try replacing `UID` with `User ID` and `PWD` with `Password`. `Data Source` has to be `SqlServer\Instance` not `SqlServer\Database`. Leave it `SqlServer` if you are using default instance.

Comment: If you're connecting to your machine the data source should be Data Source=(local);

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you are not quite sure whether you can even connect from your desktop.  To do that use the Unified Data Link (i think that's what it was called) functionality.

Follow the directions in [this article](http://www.vbrad.com/article.aspx?id=81), it'll make sure that you can even connect from your PC.  Once you can connect, it'll give you the exact connection string that you can use in your VB app.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I followed the instructions exactly and I still have the same error occurring.

Comment: @Danger_Fox  Then you might have bigger problems.  Can you install SSMS and try to connect from that?  Also, your server name seems fishy.  You have a DB called TestDB and your instance is also called TestDB?

Comment: I'm a novice when it comes to setting up these things. Could the instance and the DB being named the same cause any issues?

Comment: @Danger_Fox There could be a myriad of issues here.  First off, can you connect to SQL Server from the box where it's installed?  If you can from there, but not elsewhere, then remote connectivity isn't enabled.  Start from there.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in responding to this. I can connect to the SQL Server from the box that it's installed on. However, I'm running this application on the same box.

Answer (score 0):

I would check to see if WIN-HO6SNPJR0ST\TestDB has TCP/IP enabled for remote connections ans also check the firewall on WIN-HO6SNPJR0ST that it is allowing access to port 1433 (default sql port)

Rgds

J.